# How can I recreate a triode plate characteristics graph using a matematical formula?

Tags: pspice, vacuum-tube

Vacuum tube data sheets often include a graph of plate current vs. plate voltage for various grid voltages. For example, this screenshot from the GE 12AX7 data sheet:

[image: 12AX7 Plate Characteristics]

I would like to create this same graph (or a close approximation) using modern software, like gnuplot, so I can programmatically draw load lines, rather than drawing with pencil on a paper copy.

I have found a formula (from [this source](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4419-9536-0%2F1.pdf)) that I think will do the trick:

I<sub>P</sub> = k (V<sub>P</sub> + μ V<sub>G</sub>) <sup>3/2</sup>

μ is from the data sheet. The plate and grid voltages are known inputs. The trouble is, I don't know what `k` represents. I'm assuming it's a constant that varies by the particular model of triode being used.

Duncan Amps has [PSpice models](http://www.duncanamps.com/spicevalvesgt.html) of several vacuum tubes. (Shown below.)

I'm thinking these might be useful in determining the value of `k` that I'm missing in the formula. My problem is I don't know enough about PSpice models to puzzle it out.

So here are my questions:

1. Is my method for plotting the plate characteristics using the formula a sound idea?
2. If so, is it possible to determine the `k` value using the PSpice models and how would that be done?

If I can figure out the `k` value, getting the formula into gnuplot should be easy.

Duncan Amps PSpice Models:

```
**********************************************************************
* Duncan Amplfication Generic Triode Model (PSpice Implementation)
* Copyright (C)1997-2004 Duncan Amplfication
* Unauthorised Commercial use prohibited
* Please refer to documentation at http://www.duncanamps.com
*
* $MODEL_VERSION$ 4.1
* $AUTOGENERATED$ 23/01/2004 20:24:26 
**********************************************************************
* CURRENT MODEL SET AND VERSIONS:
*
*       2A3                 [3.2, 09/08/2003 ]
*       3CX300              [3.1, 05/01/1998 ]
*       SV6AS7              [3.0, 30/12/1997 ]
*       6BM8 / ECL82        [3.0, 31/12/1997 ]
*       6DJ8 / ECC88        [3.0, 15/08/1998 ]
*       6N1P                [3.0, 25/01/1998 ]
*       6SN7GTB             [3.1, 05/01/1998 ]
*       12AT7 / ECC81       [3.1, 05/01/1998 ]
*       12AU7 / ECC82       [3.2, 01/05/2002 ]
*       12AX7 / ECC83       [3.0, 30/12/1997 ]
*       76                  [3.0, 12/02/1998 ]
*       300B                [3.1, 06/01/1998 ]
*       SV572-3             [3.0, 31/12/1997 ]
*       SV572-10            [3.0, 20/06/1998 ]
*       5751                [3.0, 15/02/1998 ]
**********************************************************************
* CORE MODEL VERSION HISTORY:
*
*       1.0   23/09/1997    Initial model
*       1.1   19/11/1997    Model altered for 1 gig resistors between each node and ground
*       2.0   18/12/1997    Two new parameters, ERP and ERI added
*       3.0   30/12/1997    New parameter added, RAS
*       3.1   05/01/1998    ERI parameter removed
*       3.2   06/01/1998    Fix errors in Pspice model
*       3.3   13/01/1998    Fixed errors with CDO parameter
*       3.4   25/01/1998    Errors with heater versions using ERI  fixed
*       4.1   23/01/2004    Corrections to Pspice syntax for LTSpice
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT TRIODE A G K H1 H2
+PARAMS: RCO=1.6 RHO=10.5 HTV=6.3 HWU=10.5
+ LIP=1 LIF=3.7E-3 RAF=18E-3 RAS=1 CDO=0 RAP=4E-3
+ ERP=1.5 
+ MU0=17.3 MUR=19E-3 EMC=9.6E-6 GCO=0 GCF=213E-6
+ CGA=3.9p CGK=2.4p CAK=0.7p 

************************************************************************
*
* Heater model
*
* Can be operated from AC or DC power sources.
* NB: When operating from DC power sources, "Skip initial transient
*     solution" must be checked, to make use of this model.
*
* PARAMETERS
*
*   RCO Heater resistance cold (ohms)
*   RHO Heater resistance hot (ohms)
*   HTV Normal heater voltage (V)
*   HWU Heater time to warm up to 90% of emission (seconds)
*
************************************************************************

Rcool H1 HA {RCO}
Rload HA HB 1M
Esens HD 0  VALUE {V(HA,HB)*1000}
Epwr  HE 0  VALUE {V(H1,H2)*V(HD)/(PWR({HTV},2)/{RHO})}
RH1   HE HF 91k
CH1   HF 0  {HWU/1E6}
EH2   HG 0  VALUE {V(HF)}
RH2   HG HH 270k
CH2   HH 0  {HWU/1E6}
EH3   HJ 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(HH)-0.75,0,1E6)*4}
RH3   HJ HK 91k
CH3   HK 0  {HWU/1E6}
Ghot  HB H2 VALUE {(1/(V(HG)+0.001))/({RHO}-{RCO})*V(HB,H2)}

************************************************************************
*
* Anode/grid model
*
* Models reduction in mu at large negative grid voltages
* Models change in Ra with negative grid voltages
* Models limit in Ia with high +Vg and low Va
*
* PARAMETERS
*
*   LIP Conduction limit exponent
*   LIF Conduction limit factor
*   CDO Conduction offset
*   RAF Anode resistance factor for neg grid voltages
*   RAP Anode resistance factor for positive grid voltages
*   ERP Emission power
*   MU0 Mu between grid and anode at Vg=0
*   MUR Mu reduction factor for large negative grid voltages
*   EMC Emission coefficient
*   GCO Grid current offset in volts
*   GCF Grid current scale factor
*
************************************************************************

Elim  LI 0  VALUE {PWR(LIMIT(V(A,K),0,1E6),{LIP})*{LIF}}
Egg   GG 0  VALUE {V(G,K)-{CDO}}
Erpf  RP 0  VALUE {1-PWR(LIMIT(-V(GG)*{RAF},0,0.999),{RAS})+LIMIT(V(GG),0,1E6)*{RAP}}
Egr   GR 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(GG),0,1E6)+LIMIT((V(GG))*(1+V(GG)*{MUR}),0,-1E6)}
Eem   EM 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(A,K)+V(GR)*{MU0},0,1E6)}
Eep   EP 0  VALUE {PWR(V(EM),ERP)*{EMC}*V(RP)}
Eel   EL 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(EP),0,V(LI))}
Eld   LD 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(EP)-V(LI),0,1E6)}
Ga    A  K  VALUE {V(HK)*V(EL)}

************************************************************************
*
* Grid current model
*
* Models grid current, along with rise in grid current at low Va
*
************************************************************************
Egf   GF 0  VALUE {PWR(LIMIT(V(G,K)-{GCO},0,1E6),1.5)*{GCF}}
Gg    G  K  VALUE {(V(GF)+V(LD))*V(HK)}

*
* Capacitances and anti-float resistors
*
CM1 G   K   {CGK}
CM2 A   G   {CGA}
CM3 A   K   {CAK}
RF1 A   0   1000MEG
RF2 G   0   1000MEG
RF3 K   0   1000MEG

.ENDS

.SUBCKT TRIODENH A G K
+PARAMS: LIP=1 LIF=3.7E-3 RAF=18E-3 RAS=1 CDO=0 RAP=4E-3
+ ERP=1.5
+ MU0=17.3 MUR=19E-3 EMC=9.6E-6 GCO=0 GCF=213E-6
+ CGA=3.9p CGK=2.4p CAK=0.7p 

************************************************************************
*
* Anode/grid model
*
* Models reduction in mu at large negative grid voltages
* Models change in Ra with negative grid voltages
* Models limit in Ia with high +Vg and low Va
*
* PARAMETERS
*
*   LIP Conduction limit exponent
*   LIF Conduction limit factor
*   CDO Conduction offset
*   RAF Anode resistance factor for neg grid voltages
*   RAP Anode resistance factor for positive grid voltages
*   ERP Emission power
*   MU0 Mu between grid and anode at Vg=0
*   MUR Mu reduction factor for large negative grid voltages
*   EMC Emission coefficient
*   GCO Grid current offset in volts
*   GCF Grid current scale factor
*
************************************************************************

Elim  LI 0  VALUE {PWR(LIMIT(V(A,K),0,1E6),{LIP})*{LIF}}
Egg   GG 0  VALUE {V(G,K)-{CDO}}
Erpf  RP 0  VALUE {1-PWR(LIMIT(-V(GG)*{RAF},0,0.999),{RAS})+LIMIT(V(GG),0,1E6)*{RAP}}
Egr   GR 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(GG),0,1E6)+LIMIT((V(GG))*(1+V(GG)*{MUR}),0,-1E6)}
Eem   EM 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(A,K)+V(GR)*{MU0},0,1E6)}
Eep   EP 0  VALUE {PWR(V(EM),ERP)*{EMC}*V(RP)}
Eel   EL 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(EP),0,V(LI))}
Eld   LD 0  VALUE {LIMIT(V(EP)-V(LI),0,1E6)}
Ga    A  K  VALUE {V(EL)}

************************************************************************
*
* Grid current model
*
* Models grid current, along with rise in grid current at low Va
*
************************************************************************
Egf   GF 0  VALUE {PWR(LIMIT(V(G,K)-{GCO},0,1E6),1.5)*{GCF}}
Gg    G  K  VALUE {(V(GF)+V(LD))}

*
* Capacitances and anti-float resistors
*
CM1 G   K   {CGK}
CM2 A   G   {CGA}
CM3 A   K   {CAK}
RF1 A   0   1000MEG
RF2 G   0   1000MEG
RF3 K   0   1000MEG

.ENDS
**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 2A3
* MODEL:   NH2A3
* NOTES:   No heater model (virtual cathode)
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH2A3 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1.5 LIF= 0.003 RAF= 1.92357959289845E-02 RAS= 5.31355720568454E-02 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0.005 ERP= 1.55 
+ MU0= 4.2 MUR= 0.001023047 EMC= 0.0000868 
+ GCO=-0.2 GCF= 0.00001 
+ CGA=1.65E-11 CGK=7.50E-12 CAK=5.50E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 3CX300
* MODEL:   NH3CX300
* NOTES:   No heater model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH3CX300 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1.5 LIF= 10 RAF= 0.00536 RAS= 1 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0.005 ERP= 1.25 
+ MU0= 8.321 MUR= 0.0012 EMC= 0.000533 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0.0001 
+ CGA=1.00E-11 CGK=2.50E-11 CAK=1.00E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: SV6AS7
* MODEL:   NHSV6AS7
* NOTES:   No heater model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NHSV6AS7 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1 LIF= 0.01 RAF= 0.0058 RAS= 0.7 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0.035 ERP= 1.5 
+ MU0= 2.05 MUR= 0.0017 EMC= 0.0005 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0 
+ CGA=1.10E-11 CGK=8.00E-12 CAK=3.00E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 6BM8 / ECL82
* MODEL:   NH6BM8
* NOTES:   No heater or grid model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH6BM8 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1.5 LIF= 10 RAF= 0.030667 RAS= 5 CDO=-0.5 
+ RAP= 0.587 ERP= 1.5 
+ MU0= 50 MUR= 0.035 EMC= 0.00000256 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0 
+ CGA=4.00E-12 CGK=2.70E-12 CAK=4.00E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 6DJ8 / ECC88
* MODEL:   NH6DJ8
* NOTES:   No heater or grid current model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH6DJ8 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1.5 LIF= 10 RAF= 0.09 RAS= 0.2 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0 ERP= 1.35 
+ MU0= 33 MUR= 0.02 EMC= 0.0000795 
+ GCO=-0.2 GCF= 0 
+ CGA=1.40E-12 CGK=3.30E-12 CAK=1.80E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 6N1P
* MODEL:   NH6N1P
* NOTES:   No heater/grid model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH6N1P A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1.5 LIF= 10 RAF= 0.01 RAS= 1 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0 ERP= 1.6 
+ MU0= 37.5 MUR= 0.01 EMC= 0.000005 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0 
+ CGA=1.60E-12 CGK=3.20E-12 CAK=1.50E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 6SN7GTB
* MODEL:   6SN7GTB
* NOTES:   Has heater model (one half of heater)
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT 6SN7GTB A G K H1 H2
XV1 A G K H1 H2 TRIODE
+PARAMS: RCO= 3.2 RHO= 21 HTV= 6.3 HWU= 10.5 
+ LIP= 1 LIF= 0.0037 RAF= 0.02 RAS= 2 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0.002 ERP= 1.4 
+ MU0= 19.2642 MUR= 0.006167 EMC= 0.0000189 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0.000213 
+ CGA=3.90E-12 CGK=2.40E-12 CAK=7.00E-13
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 6SN7GTB
* MODEL:   NH6SN7GTB
* NOTES:   No heater model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH6SN7GTB A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1 LIF= 0.0037 RAF= 0.02 RAS= 2 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0.002 ERP= 1.4 
+ MU0= 19.2642 MUR= 0.006167 EMC= 0.0000189 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0.000213 
+ CGA=3.90E-12 CGK=2.40E-12 CAK=7.00E-13
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 12AT7 / ECC81
* MODEL:   12AT7
* NOTES:   Heater model for one half of heater (6.3V)
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT 12AT7 A G K H1 H2
XV1 A G K H1 H2 TRIODE
+PARAMS: RCO= 6.2 RHO= 42 HTV= 6.3 HWU= 10.5 
+ LIP= 1 LIF= 0.0037 RAF= 0.09869 RAS= 1 CDO=-0.5 
+ RAP= 0.1 ERP= 1.4 
+ MU0= 45.093 MUR= 0.012937 EMC= 0.00000863 
+ GCO=-0.5 GCF= 0.00012 
+ CGA=1.60E-12 CGK=2.30E-12 CAK=4.00E-13
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 12AT7 / ECC81
* MODEL:   NH12AT7
* NOTES:   No heater model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH12AT7 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1 LIF= 0.0037 RAF= 0.09869 RAS= 1 CDO=-0.5 
+ RAP= 0.1 ERP= 1.4 
+ MU0= 45.093 MUR= 0.012937 EMC= 0.00000863 
+ GCO=-0.5 GCF= 0.00012 
+ CGA=1.60E-12 CGK=2.30E-12 CAK=4.00E-13
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 12AU7 / ECC82
* MODEL:   12AU7
* NOTES:   Heater model for one half of heater (6.3V)
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT 12AU7 A G K H1 H2
XV1 A G K H1 H2 TRIODE
+PARAMS: RCO= 6.2 RHO= 42 HTV= 6.3 HWU= 10.5 
+ LIP= 1 LIF= 0.0037 RAF= 0.024778659 RAS= 2.040491735 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0.18 ERP= 1.35 
+ MU0= 14.27427 MUR= 0.005857103 EMC= 0.0000236 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0.00012 
+ CGA=1.60E-12 CGK=1.80E-12 CAK=4.50E-13
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 12AU7 / ECC82
* MODEL:   NH12AU7
* NOTES:   No heater model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH12AU7 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1 LIF= 0.0037 RAF= 0.000001 RAS= 2.065382774 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0.18 ERP= 1.4 
+ MU0= 17.08958652 MUR= 0.010938375 EMC= 0.0000183 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0.00012 
+ CGA=1.60E-12 CGK=1.80E-12 CAK=4.50E-13
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 12AX7 / ECC83
* MODEL:   12AX7
* NOTES:   Heater model for one half of heater (6.3V)
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT 12AX7 A G K H1 H2
XV1 A G K H1 H2 TRIODE
+PARAMS: RCO= 6.2 RHO= 42 HTV= 6.3 HWU= 10.5 
+ LIP= 1.5 LIF= 0.000016 RAF= 0.076498 RAS= 1 CDO=-0.53056 
+ RAP= 0.18 ERP= 1.5 
+ MU0= 87.302 MUR=-0.013621 EMC= 0.00000111 
+ GCO=-0.2 GCF= 0.00001 
+ CGA=3.90E-12 CGK=2.40E-12 CAK=7.00E-13
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 12AX7 / ECC83
* MODEL:   NH12AX7
* NOTES:   No heater model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH12AX7 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1.5 LIF= 0.000016 RAF= 0.076498 RAS= 1 CDO=-0.53056 
+ RAP= 0.18 ERP= 1.5 
+ MU0= 87.302 MUR=-0.013621 EMC= 0.00000111 
+ GCO=-0.2 GCF= 0.00001 
+ CGA=3.90E-12 CGK=2.40E-12 CAK=7.00E-13
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 76
* MODEL:   NH76
* NOTES:   No heater/grid model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH76 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1 LIF= 10 RAF= 0.015 RAS= 1.8 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0 ERP= 1.6 
+ MU0= 12.8 MUR= 0.001 EMC= 0.000008 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0 
+ CGA=2.80E-12 CGK=3.50E-12 CAK=2.50E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 300B
* MODEL:   NH300B
* NOTES:   No heater/grid model (virtual cathode)
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH300B A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1 LIF= 10 RAF= 0.00311 RAS= 1.013608 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0 ERP= 1.5 
+ MU0= 3.7992 MUR= 0.000362 EMC= 0.000116 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0 
+ CGA=1.50E-11 CGK=9.00E-12 CAK=4.30E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: SV572-3
* MODEL:   SV5723
* NOTES:   No heater model (virtual cathode)
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT SV5723 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1 LIF= 0.0018 RAF= 0.0012 RAS= 0.5 CDO= 0 
+ RAP= 0 ERP= 1.4 
+ MU0= 3.79928 MUR= 0.0002 EMC= 0.0000425 
+ GCO= 0 GCF= 0.0000349 
+ CGA=4.00E-12 CGK=4.00E-12 CAK=1.00E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: SV572-10
* MODEL:   SV57210
* NOTES:   This model is not accurate for Vg >= +60V
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT SV57210 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1.4 LIF= 0.0008 RAF= 0.001 RAS= 1 CDO= 0 
+ RAP=-0.00117 ERP= 1.38 
+ MU0= 10 MUR= 0.0001 EMC= 0.0000272 
+ GCO=-0.2 GCF= 0.0003 
+ CGA=5.00E-12 CGK=6.40E-12 CAK=1.00E-12
.ENDS

**********************************************************************
* GENERIC: 5751
* MODEL:   NH5751
* NOTES:   No heater model
**********************************************************************
.SUBCKT NH5751 A G K
XV1 A G K TRIODENH
+PARAMS: LIP= 1.5 LIF= 0.000016 RAF= 0.075772 RAS= 1 CDO=-0.53056 
+ RAP= 0.131285 ERP= 1.5 
+ MU0= 62.94685 MUR=-0.0111 EMC= 0.00000142 
+ GCO=-0.2 GCF= 0.00001 
+ CGA=1.40E-12 CGK=1.40E-12 CAK=4.50E-13
.ENDS
```

Comment: @Andyaka I probably could use spice modeling in KiCad, but I'd like to be able to create the plate characteristics graph to use as illustrations in documentation. Gnuplot is handy for that sort of thing, and very customizable, whereas grabbing screenshots out of another program can be tedious.

Comment: Dave, you've basically shown us that you can find one equation in one place and a PSpice model from somewhere else, that neither of these things help you right now, and you want someone else to understand the circumstances under which you want "convenience" (but without telling us more about the context where you use gnuplot -- itself only a suggestion from you that leaves us still wondering if other options you have available but remain unmentioned might be easier) and do the work of pasting these two things (assuming it can be done) into an arrangement, by guessing at your circumstances?

Comment: @jonk I'm using gnuplot because I've used it before and had good results getting what I wanted out of it. I figure if I can get the right formula in it, I can get the graph I want. I will edit my question to add some of the results I've gotten so far and the gnuplot commands I used to get those results. As to why... just to see if it can be done and to understand it better. I thought that perhaps someone may have tried this before.

Comment: I use Latex for writing. And in a case like this I'd simply develop the code using tikz or some other package that is already available for the purpose (there's lots to choose from.) As to creating the curves, you have everything you need in the PSpice model -- and then some. I'd actually try to use the general triode model as the base and then make some macros to call it for various tubes, their specific parameters, and what curves I needed to generate. It's not complicated. Just takes "sit down time." So I'm just not sure what's stopping you, I guess. I don't get the barrier you face.

Comment: What's stopping me is my limited understanding of the spice model. I can figure out the easy bits, like `CGA=3.9p` is the capacitance between the grid and anode (plate). What's stumping me is where to find the relationship between anode and current for different grid voltages. I'm sure it's in there, probably under the comment header for `Anode/grid model`, but I'm not skilled enough with spice to find it.

Comment: That's the "sit down time." I *am* familiar with the Spice card deck and can read it, fluently. But I'd still need to sit down with it and draw things out in pretty pictures, first, to see what they are doing and why. Are you familiar with electronics? If so, this is just what I said... sitting down with the cards they wrote and placing them into a nice-looking schematic, then analyzing it for what you need. It's possible -- no promises of course, that there will be a "k" that comes out from the process. But then, it's even more likely that the model they have is a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: If it is more sophisticated, then you may want that better model for your purposes and the other model isn't so good. On the other hand, if you have already determined that the simple model with "k" does what you need, then I don't see why you need the Spice model. You can grab up charts and just "find the k" through a manual process of your own with each datasheet. If it is only one unknown, it's not going to be hard. You could even write up a Python script, plug in a few data points from each chart, and let it tell you the "k". I just don't see barriers, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In another forum, someone said this coefficient (k) used in the triode equation is know as 'perveance'. I believe this is also the 'emission coefficient' or EMC in the spice model referenced in the question. The value for a 12AX7 is 0.00000111

Using this value for `k` in the triode equation gets close to matching the curves on the data sheet. Taking an iterative approach to refining it, I ended up with k=0.0000018 being a better fit. But, this is still just a rough approximation.

The following gnuplot script will draw the plate current as a function of plate voltage for various values of Vg, starting with Vg = 0 and progressing in -1/2 volt increments to -3.5.

```
f(x) = k * (x + mu * Vg) ** 3/2

mu = 100
k=0.0000018
set xlabel "Plate Voltage (V)"
set xrange [0:500]
set ylabel "Plate Current (mA)"
set yrange [0:3.5]
set multiplot
set key off

Vg = 0
plot f(x)
Vg = -0.5
plot f(x)
Vg = -1.0
plot f(x)
Vg = -1.5
plot f(x)
Vg = -2.0
plot f(x)
Vg = -2.5
plot f(x)
Vg = -3.0
plot f(x)
Vg = -3.5
plot f(x)
```

The resulting graph looks like this:

[image: plate characteristics]

So, to answer my two questions...

1. Using the formula works, but it's a very rough approximation.
2. I'm pretty sure the value of k is what the spice model calls EMC, but because the formula doesn't take all factors into account, k needed to be tweaked a bit to make the graph look right.

All in all, I think I need a more comprehensive model than just the triode equation.